# Three Votes for Two Moderator Candidates for One Position

Tags: support, election, moderators

In the present Moderator Election there are but two candidates and I am being prompted to vote three times. Since I don't live in Chicago I would like to know how I am to accomplish this?

If I simply leave my first two choices will those votes be counted? When I cast my 'second place' vote I am told I have one vote remaining. I don't see a "cast my ballot button" to say I am done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just case your first and second choice and your votes will be counted appropriately.  These elections were designed for a higher number of candidates but this will not preclude them from working with only two.

Comment: Your second choice is irrelevant with single transferable voting; it's not used until your first choice candidate is eliminated, and at that point, your second choice has already won.

Comment: The second choice is used, in this case, when a moderator retires, or when a moderator is made part of the Stack Exchange staff; in those cases, the next voted candidate replaces the missing moderator. That is what happened on Stack Overflow when Anna Lear was made community manager; [who replaced her](http://stackoverflow.com/election/2) was the 5th user as number of votes in the last election.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: But there are only two choices. So second choice votes are still irrelevant; the next voted one is *always* the other... unless *everyone* voted for one person, and didn't cast a second choice vote.

Comment: @jefromi It could be nobody has chosen me as second choice, and Stack Exchange would not consider me as "replacement" candidate in the case a moderator retires from the position before the next elections are done. That is something only the Stack Exchange staff knows.